# What's the purpose of randomCounts[index]++;?

Tags: java, processing

I'm quite new to Java programming and was actually looking at Daniel Shiffman's nature of code example of Random Distribution.

Can I know what's the purpose of randomCounts[index]++; ? It says counter so what does it actually do? What value will it be everytime the function draw() runs?

1. I know randomCounts has 20 storage.
2. index is always random with value between 0 - 20.

but just don't understand the randomCounts[index]++.

```
    // An array to keep track of how often random numbers are picked
    float[] randomCounts;

    void setup() {
    size(800,200);
    randomCounts = new float[20];
    }

    void draw() {
    background(255);

    // Pick a random number and increase the count
    int index = int(random(randomCounts.length));
    randomCounts[index]++;

    // Draw a rectangle to graph results
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(127);

    int w = width/randomCounts.length;

    for (int x = 0; x < randomCounts.length; x++) {
    rect(x*w,height-randomCounts[x],w-1,randomCounts[x]);
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ++ operator increment a variable. So in your example, `randomCounts[index]++;` increment the float at the index `index` in the `randomCounts` array.

See this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: hey thanks so much! I understand now. So it's saying that:  randomCounts[index]=randomCounts[index]+1; It means when the array gets selected, increase the height by 1. Thanks so much Magus!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is within the code comment directly above the statement.

```
    randomCounts[index]++;
```

Increments the count by one. index is the position of the `float` inside the array `randomCounts`, and that is what is being incremented.